# Integrate PayPal Payment with user paying to another user (PHP)

Tags: paypal

I need to integrate PayPal Payment in my website, but I need that an user pay a product to another user. How can I do that?

Note: I never did nothing related to PayPal payments, so if you someone can give me a clear help I appreciate.

Comment: What language? Have you tried something?

Comment: Oh yea, sorry. I want to adapt it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Integrate a version of [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), and set the custom payee variable

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/